# WSO2 IoT: Creating a new device type

Tags: wso2, iot, wso2-iot

I am creating the new device from the documentation provided in this link (https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-maven-plugin.git).

I performed the following  steps

Step 1: Installing the Maven Archetype. Everything went okay! The maven archtype installed was

```
git clone -b v1.0.0 --single-branch https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-maven-plugin.git
```

In Step 2: Creating a new device type, when I perform the command `mvn archetype: generate -DarchetypeCatalog = local`. The output does not show me the archetype for me to choose. Look at the output of this command:

```
C:\Users\eliazar.carvalho\Documents\Tools\WSO2\wso2iot-3.0.0\samples>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------    ---
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to initial list)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): :
```

What could be going wrong?

I am using WSO2 IoT Server 3.0
and OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. This is how I fixed it.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -X
```

Will give you the exact local catalog file path it is being read. For me it was `~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml`.

But actualy my local repo catalog file is on `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`. So I copied `archetype-catalog.xml` into the correct path with following command.

```
cp ~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml ~/.m2/repository/
```

Now it works fine. It seems we need to update maven-archetype-plugin version in mentioned repository.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.
But I realized that only one archetype is made available, unlike the documentation that lists 4 different archetypes.

Archetypes made available to me
1: location -> org.wso2.cdmf.devicetype: cdmf-devicetype-archetype (WSO2 CDMF Device Type Archetype)

Could you tell me why?

Comment: That's because you don't have built those repos thus local catalog will not contain those archetypes. BTW for generating a new device type we are only interested in org.wso2.cdmf.devicetype: cdmf-devicetype-archetype archetype.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 IoT 3.1.0 is released and it includes 3 ways of introducing a new device type.

1. [Writing Java Extension using maven archetype](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Writing+Device+Plugins+via+Java+Code)
2. [Descriptor based model](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Writing+Device+Type+via+the+Template)
3. [API based model](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+APIs)

Please refer more information [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Writing+Device+Types)

Comment: Please refer following documentation for more information. http://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/07/an-introduction-to-wso2-iot-architecture/

Comment: 1. Writing Java Extension using maven archetype -
 https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Writing+Device+Plugins+via+Java+Code

Comment: 2. Descriptor based model - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Writing+Device+Type+via+the+Template

Comment: 3. API based model - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+APIs
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Creating+a+New+Device+Type+via+the+Device+Management+Console

Comment: Please update your answer and write references in it.